# Adding button to right side of Hub header

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Unlike default "Back" button, I want to have "Add" button to the **right side** of the `Hub` header. Also that button should remain at its place like how header do. (so that it can be accessible from any `HubSection`)

Expected result:
[image]

Currently getting:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Instead of placing the button inside `<Hub.HeaderTemplate>` tag, place it in the `Grid` that contains the `Hub` itself.

for example,

```
<Grid>
   <Hub>
        ....
   </Hub>
   <Button>
        ....
   </Button>
</Grid>
```